# Java - Regex - Can a capturing group value be used in the definition of another capturing group?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a string that follows this format:

```
"<N>|<M>|<word_of_size_N><word_of_size_M>"
```

Is there a *single* regex that can find the values of `<N>` and `<M>` and use those values to extract the `<word_of_size_N>` and `<word_of_size_M>` ?

I have tried the following snippet

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegexExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "5|3|hello123";
        String regex = "^(\\d+)\\|(\\d+)\\|(\\w{\\1})(\\w{\\2})$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String n = matcher.group(1);
            String m = matcher.group(2);
            String wordN = matcher.group(3);
            String wordM = matcher.group(4);
            System.out.println("The input string matches the regex pattern.");
            System.out.println("N = " + n + ", M = " + m);
            System.out.println("word of size N = " + wordN);
            System.out.println("word of size M = " + wordM);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The input string does not match the regex pattern.");
        }
    }
}
```

But it raises an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 17
^(\d+)\|(\d+)\|(\w{\1})(\w{\2})$
                 ^
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:2028)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3323)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2214)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2069)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:3060)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2124)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2069)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1783)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1429)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1069)
    at RegexExample.main(RegexExample.java:7)
```

I know i could simply do it in two steps

- use a regex (or other string manipulation) to find `<N>` and `<M>`
- read two substrings of length `<N>` and `<M>`

But i'm curious to know if regex can reference itself in some way.

*Bonus:* are there other regex engines that can do this?

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate that you can use a back reference to match something later in the pattern, but I think referring to a back reference in a count specification is not allowed.

Comment: I don't think any regex engine can do this, what you can do is read `N`, `M`, and one word, using regex. And then check whether `N + M` is the length of the matched word.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Regexes don't parse strings to their numerical value, giving access to that numerical value for use as a qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a capturing group value be used in the definition of another capturing group?

generally speaking - yes. you can write your own pattern compilation logic to support such feature.

is this feature supported by Jdk - no (afaik).

also you need to keep in mind a **type** of the back reference - its `char[]`, not a `number`. thus `\\w{\\1}` would require some non-trivial assumptions or explicit type conversion syntax.

also while keeping in mind back reference **type**, you can make quite tricky manipulations, e.g.:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^<(\\w+)>(.*?)</((?:(?!\\1).)*)>$");
Stream.of(
    "<leg>hello123</leg>",
    "<leg>hello123</hand>"
).forEach(input -> {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    System.out.println("input: " + input);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("group(" + i + "): " + matcher.group(i));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("The input string does not match the regex pattern.");
    }
});
```

Output:

```
input: <leg>hello123</leg>
The input string does not match the regex pattern.

input: <leg>hello123</hand>
group(0): <leg>hello123</hand>
group(1): leg
group(2): hello123
group(3): hand
```